# AutoIt - How to click on a link matches a certain pattern

Tags: autoit

I need to be able to search through a source code of a web page 
for a link matches a specific pattern 
and if there's a match - open it in a new window.
I don't care about the browser, could be either IE or Chrome.

What I was able to achieve so far (which is not even close to what I need) is this:

```
MsgBox(0,"message box",StringRegExp("www.example.com/d12345/abcde.html","www.example.com/d\d*/abcde.html"))
```

So basically, if the string www.example.com/d12345/abcde.html exists in the source code, I am getting '1' in return.
What I need is,
that if a string matches the pattern - open the link in a new window.
Could someone suggest how to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get all links (complete url) in your file.
2. search through those links for your match
3. If match then Shellexecute the url.